# What are options for specifying the schema of an http document

Tags: rest, content-type

I'm working on a RESTful webservice that could possibly transport different kinds of payloads, specifically different structures serialized as either xml or json.  I know I can set the content-type header to application/xml or application/json, but I would like to also specify the structure of the document (so, for xml, I would like to give the schema).

Googling around I found application/wrml (http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/11/18/rest-api-design-putting-the-type-in-content-type/) which seems like a good idea, but not widely accepted yet.  Are there any other ways to achieve the same thing?

EDIT:  How about using media type parameters (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) for something like

```
content-type: application/xml; schema=http://myserver.com/myApplication/schema.xsd
```

Comment: Why wont linking the schema in the XML itself suffice ? What problem does this solve ?

Comment: I'm giving a specific example of a generic problem.  The payload could also be JSON, or a CSV file, or whatever, and I'd like to some document describing it.

Comment: I see. I'm not aware of a standard and don't find the need for one. Documents are either schemaless or have hints to the schema structure in themselves (like XSD or the first row of a CSV). I still don't see a value addition in decoupling this information. Is including this additional information under your control at the moment ? If not you might have to settle for a propriety solution like the one you mentioned.

Comment: Your two examples are good ones - but, just for the sake of the conversation, how about JSON documents?  IMHO, they don't describe themselves...

Comment: I agree that they do not describe themselves, but that is why devs love them so much. Instead of re-running codegen to generate an updated model, you can refer to a new key in a dictionary (PHP / Python) or let a framework (like gson in java) take care of serialization / deserialization. I've never had to define a schema for JSON even when I change the structure later.